# Parse magento-type parameter value string

Tags: magento-1.9

Magento url structure is

```
/controller/action/param1/param1value/param2/param2value/
```

Magento decodes this for you, so in the controller you can call

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('param1')
```

to get the value of `param1`.

Now, I have string of type `param1/param1value/param2/param2value`
and I would need to get the parameter value pairs out of it.

Can I utilise Magento classes/functions to implement this? E.g. have the request class do the parsing for me. I tried to find this in Magento codebase (it has to be there somewhere, right), but was not able to locate it.

I have Magento 1.

Comment: Did you mean `getParams()`? It should give you an array with all values.

Comment: Yes, but the params are not in the request, but in a similarly formatted string. Not a big deal to parse myself, but as I know there is a functionality for that build in, would rather use tha.

Comment: What do you mean with "are not in the request"?

Comment: I'v reverted your last edit, because its missleading. You can get a single URL parameter using `getParam('key')`. To get all use `getParams()` (without parameter) to get an key-value array of all URL prarams. `$args = $this->getParams(); echo $args['param2'];` schould give you `param2value `.

Answer (score 1):

Use getParams() method to get the list of params.

```
$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

foreach ($params as $param => $value) {
/* This loop iterates through the set of params */
}
```